# Bubble sort in Linux/Unix shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to perform bubble sort is Unix shell script. Why is my code not working?

```
a=(10 8 20 25 12)

for ((i=0;i<5;i++))
do
 for((j=0;j<5;j++))
 do
if ((${a[j]} > ${a[$((j+1))]}))
then
  v=${a[$j]}
  a[$j]=${a[$((j+1))]}
  a[$((j+1))]=$v
    fi
 done
done
    echo ${a[*]}
    echo "end..."
```

Comment: You know there's a `sort` command right?

Comment: @WaleedKhan sort uses Mergesort. which is faster than bubble ( O(nlgn) < O(n^2) ), OP may be looking for a slower one. as far as I know, bubble is the slowest.  I guess this is a homework.

Comment: *“as far as I know, bubble is the slowest”* What about lucksort?

Comment: And what about [sleep sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Sleep_sort)?

Comment: In some sense, sleep sort is very fast; with a clock of infinite resolution, it's O(n) by normalizing the keys to fit in a fixed interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is homework. therefore I don't give codes, just point out the errors in your codes:

`for((j=0;j<5;j++))` then read `a[j+1]`, here would be problem because when `j=4`, `j+1` doesn't exist

fix that, your program will sort.

Comment: thank u .. the loop should be for((j=0;j<5-1;j++))
thanks a lot .. :) in fact my program was doing the sorting right but there was an error . now it is fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "Enter size of array";
read  n; #get the size of array from user.
echo "Enter the array";
read -a arr;  #get the array form user eg: 2 3 4 5 6
echo "Orignal array is: ${arr[*]}"; #print orignal array

flag=1;
for (( i = 0; i < $n-1; i++ ))
do
    flag=0;
    for ((j = 0; j < $n-1-$i; j++ ))
    do
        if [[ ${arr[$j]} -gt ${arr[$j+1]} ]]
        then
            temp=${arr[$j]};
            arr[$j]=${arr[$j+1]};
            arr[$j+1]=$temp;
            flag=1;
        fi
    done

    if [[ $flag -eq 0 ]]; then
        break;
    fi
      
done
echo "Final sorted Array is ${arr[*]}";
```